# Fastest Way to Load a Screenshot Into Memory for CV Template Matching

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

What's the fastest way, in ubuntu 11.10, to take a screenshot with python and convert the screenshot into a format that's compatible with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720168/image-in-image-algorithm) about image template matching?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux for a starting point? Converting to a nice format for OpenCV comes next. As for speed, why do you need it to be fast?

Comment: @batbrat I'm making an image recognition bot, so speed is preferable vs some solutions that i saw which took several seconds to process a screenshot. I'm not going to nitpick over subsecond times though, as long as it's reasonably fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[xpresser](https://launchpad.net/xpresser) is a project that works in ubuntu that also uses opencv. In the [xutils module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~niemeyer/xpresser/trunk/view/head:/xpresser/xutils.py) there's a function to take a screenshot which is as follows:

```
def take_screenshot(x=0, y=0, width=None, height=None):
    window = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
    if not (width and height):
        size = window.get_size()
        if not width:
            width = size[0]
        if not height:
            height = size[1]
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, width, height)
    pixbuf = pixbuf.get_from_drawable(window, window.get_colormap(),
                                      x, y, 0, 0, width, height)
    array = pixbuf.get_pixels_array()
    return Image("screenshot", array=array,
                 width=array.shape[1], height=array.shape[0])
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This actually doesn't work. At pixbuf.get_pixels_array() I get "aborted" as the output and it just stops.

Comment: That's strange. I'm also using Ubuntu 11.10 with python 2.7.2-7ubuntu2 and python-gtk2 2.24.0-2 and it works for me.

Comment: I'm working on making sure that gtk is working properly for me. I'm in a VM that I just set up today running under windows 7, so I might not have fully configured it yet

Comment: I updated again and it works file. I'm going pixbuf => PIL image => cv image and it looks to be quite sufficiently fast.